# Return all table A rows even if they do not exist in table C

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select a.x, b.x, c.x, d.x, e.x

from A a

inner join B b
on a.col1 = b.y
and b.col1 = 'string_value'

inner join AC ac
on a.col1 = ac.col1

inner join C c
on c.col1 = ac.col2

inner join CDE cde
on cde.col1 = c.col1

inner join D d
on cde.col2 = d.col1

inner join E e
on cde.col3 = e.col1
```

Table AC maps values between tables A and C. Table CDE maps values between tables C, D, and E.

I have a problem. Column a.x is mapped towards column c.x as expected. **Except** when the C table does not have a value equal to the one in the A table. The query returns **only** the rows from A which have a.col1 present in ac.col1.

I would like to have the query **also** return the rows from A which do not have a.col1 present in ac.col1.

I thought this was because of the inner join of AC. I have tried left, right, and full outer joins of AC without getting the results I need. I have also tried something like:

```
inner join AC ac
on a.col1 = ac.col1
or (a.col1 is not null and ac.col1 is null)
```

Which has not given me any fewer/more rows. To reiterate - I need more rows. I need all rows from A and then map the other table column values towards them, even if the other tables may not have any rows to give. Please help if you can and please excuse me if the description seems confusing.

Comment: Learn about `OUTER` joins, such as `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `FULL`.

Comment: Replace the `inner join` with `left join` throughout the query.

Comment: Using a `left join` solved my problems. Thanks. I understand this much better now. Not sure why I missed this while reading yesterday.